# How to print / append on the middle of the html div a value from a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

On a nav menu with onclick function [(example here)](https://jsfiddle.net/pf18aumb/) that displays a div tab content I would like to pass an additional value to load a specific content. This is the current code:

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London', 'capital')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris', 'France')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo', 'Japan')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the <script>document.write(ThirdValue)</script> city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of <script>document.write(ThirdValue)</script>.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of <script>document.write(ThirdValue)</script>.</p>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName, ThirdValue) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  alert(ThirdValue);
}
```

I am not able to get the third variable within the div. I am able to see it with `alert(ThirdValue);`, but using `<script>document.write(ThirdValue)</script>` I am not able to add it within the html.

I need to add this value within the html. How can I print / append this value within the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `document.write`, since it is only working while the DOM is loading, after the DOM is ready, it won't work.

Instead place a placeholder inside the html (eg: `<p>London is the {var} city of England.</p>`), and replace it with `ThirdValue`. Here is how:

```
var text = document.getElementById(cityName).querySelector('p');
text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace('{var}',ThirdValue);
```

Full code:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, ThirdValue) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  var text = document.getElementById(cityName).querySelector('p');
  text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace('{var}',ThirdValue);
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London', 'capital')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris', 'France')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo', 'Japan')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the {var} city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of {var}.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of {var}.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, this works very well. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.